# Font Awesome icon size not increasing

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have Font Awesome icons installed on [this](http://www.fahaduddin.com/mattbertulli) site. The icons size isn't increasing even after adding the class to increase size.

```
<ul class="stay-connected-inner list-inline">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-medium fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is "the class to increase size"? fa-3? fa-3 isn't declared.

Comment: Yes. fa-3 is the class to increase the icon size.

Comment: change `fa-3` to`fa-3x`

Comment: Nop, fa-3 is not declared. just add .fa-3{font-size:20px}

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To increase icon sizes relative to their container, use the fa-lg (33% increase), fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, or fa-5x classes.

```
            <ul class="stay-connected-inner list-inline">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-medium fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 24):

font-awesome icons are texts. So use font-size to increase the size of font-awesome icons.

For eg.,

```
i {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Easiest answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  For some reason the fa class is overriding the fa-2x class on the awesome font library.  I found a blog that they knew it was an issue back in 2014 but haven't addressed it yet.  On my site I added the style class again and added !important which fixed my problem.

```html
<style>
      .fa-2x{
        font-size:2em !important;
    };
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

For font awesome icons sizing please check this link.
http://fontawesome.io/examples/

To increase icon sizes relative to their container, use the fa-lg (33% increase), fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, or fa-5x classes.

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-5x
```

Answer (score 0):

use following inline css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fa-3{
      font-size: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using font awesome or font awesome pro icons in Angular 5+ using svg with Javascript. The easy way to increase your custom font size is:

```
.svg-inline--fa{
  font-size:1.500em; //use your custom font size. If you do not want to apply the font awesome size classes
}
```

Apply this in your custom component to see the changes immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In my case setting `fa fa-5x`, or `font-size` or `height` didn't help, but:

```
 width: 20px !important; // 20px is an example value
```

Also be cautious if you have `padding` applied!